# How to move a item between two listboxes with dynamic btn and listbox with Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have come to a dead end in my knowledge of GUI and Tkinter knowledge.

Question:

I want to move items between listboxes in a "dynamic" way.

I have in my `Create_Widget()` function define a few listboxes like this. In this case `5`.

```
for lbIdx in range(1:6):
    self.listbox[lbIdx] = tk.Listbox(self.center, selectmode='multiple', height=25, 
                                     width=40, exportselection=0)
```

I have also created some buttons that appear between the listboxes:

```
# dynamic buttons
for btn_rID in range(1,6):
    self.btn_right[btn_rID] = tk.Button(self.center, text = '>>', 
                                        command=lambda i=btn_rID: self.move_item_right(i))

for btn_lID in range(1,6):
    self.btn_left[btn_lID] = tk.Button(self.center, text = '<<', 
                                       command= lambda i=btn_lID: self.move_item_left(i))
```

The buttons are using similar functions `move_item_right()` and `move_item_left()`.

The problem arises when I want to move right or left with the following code:

```
def move_item_right(self, btn_ID):
    # btn_ID holds the information of which button_idx was pressed
    idxToMove = self.listbox[btn_ID].curselection()
    itemToMove = self.listbox[btn_ID].selection_get()
    self.listbox[btn_ID+1].insert(idxToMove,itemToMove)
    self.listbox[btn_ID].delete(idxToMove)
```

I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 968, in selection_get
    return self.tk.call(('selection', 'get') + self._options(kw))
_tkinter.TclError: PRIMARY selection doesn't exist or form "STRING" not defined
```

It worked well before I started using the dynamical button definitions. But then I had do write a single function for each button call.

Can anyone interpret this strange error? When I use the debugger the debugger steps into the button definition after the

```
itemToMove = self.listbox[btn_ID].selection_get()
```

Comment: I have solved it now! Just googled a bit on the PRIMARY respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had implemented the error myself with the typo `exportselection=0` in the listbox definition.

It works well without that..

```
# solution
for lbIdx in range(1:6):
    self.listbox[lbIdx] = tk.Listbox(self.center, selectmode='multiple', height=25, 
                                     width=40)
```